# Spring+Hibernate+MS SQL: object references an unsaved transient instance child object id(primary key) cannot be zero

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm developing a web application using Spring+Hibernate+MS SQL and encountered a weird symptom:

I have parent object `A` that has a field reference (`FK`) another child object `B`. In `A`, I have annotation

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

When I call `Session.SaveOrUpdate` for `A`. Everything works fine and `B` is persisted as well except one case:

When `id field` (which is the primary key) of table B is 0, it gives exception:

> object references an unsaved transient instance...

If it is non-zero, everything is fine.

As most people suggested for the exception "object references an unsaved transient instance...", I also tried change annotation to

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER).
```

Then it gives me another error saying `Primary key cannot be NULL`...

Does anybody have any comments or explanation on this problem? Your help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provides how you map `A` and `B` , and how do you setup the object state before you call `session.SaveOrUpdate(a)`

Comment: The zero (or null) ID value is used by Hibernate to determine that it's a newly-created (i.e. transient) object.

Comment: Thanks, millhouse! That's what I have been specious of. Zero ID is special. Does that mean I have to start the primary key of table B from 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Ken.
I map A as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
.....
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="B_id")
public TableB  getB_id() {      
    return this.b_id;
}
public void setB_id(TableB  p) {        
    this.b_id= p;
}
...
}
```

and B as follows:

```
Entity
@Table(name="TableB")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
private int B_id;
private String B_name;
private String B_desc;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="B_id")    
public int getB_id()
{
    return this.B_id;
}
public void setB_id(int id)
{
    this.B_id = id;
}

@Column(name="B_name")
public String B_name()
{
    return this.B_name;
}
}
```

before calling session.SaveOrUpdate(a), i have:

```
TableA tempA = aDao.getA(id); 
TableB tempB =bDao.getB(0);
tempA.setB_id(tempB);
session.SaveOrUpdate(tempA);
```